# jQuery UI selectable widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My setup: jQuery 1.6.2, jQuery UI 1.8.15

I got the selectable interaction to work but unfortunately anchors in the element itself are not active. Here's a snippet of the code I'm working with

```
<ul id="selectable">
  <li>John Doe
      <br/>(111) 222-3333
      <br/><a href="mailto:john.doe@blah.com">john.doe@blah.com</a>
      <br/>
        <a href="/comments?user=15">3 comments</a>
        <br/>
      <br/>
      <a href="/users/15/edit">Edit</a>    
      <a href="/users/15" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
    <hr/>
  </li>
  <li>Jane Smith
      <br/>(222) 333-4444
      <br/><a href="mailto:jane.smith@blah.com">jane.smith@blah.com</a>
      <br/>
        <a href="/comments?user=17">1 comment</a>
        <br/>
      <br/>
      <a href="/users/17/edit">Edit</a>
      <a href="/users/17" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
    <hr/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As @fehays indicated, I want the anchors to simply behave like anchors inside of the selectable li. I figure I should be able to do that in this block of code but I don't know exactly what

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
      selected: function(ev, ui) {
      //insert code here?
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a click event to your anchor tags that uses javascript to open the right page.

http://jsfiddle.net/fehays/UUEwd/

```
<ul id="selectable">
  <li>John Doe
      <br/>(111) 222-3333
      <br/><a href="mailto:john.doe@blah.com">john.doe@blah.com</a>
      <br/>
      <a href="/comments?user=15">3 comments</a>
        <br/>
      <br/>
      <a href="/users/15/edit">Edit</a>

      <a href="/users/15" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
    <hr/>
  </li>

</ul>
```

js:

```
$(function(){

    $('#selectable').selectable({
        selected: function(ev, ui) {
         //maybe do something
        }
    });

    $('#selectable li a').click(function(){     
         var url = $(this).attr('href');

         if ($(this).data('confirm')) {
            var answer = confirm($(this).data('confirm'));
            var method = $(this).data('method');
            if (method && answer) {
                // execute method?
                // do redirect?
                window.location = url; 
            }
         } else {
            window.location = url;             
         }
    });

});
```

Comment: Hmm, it worked in your example but it didn't in mind, I noticed that you didn't add any selectable CSS, could that be why?

Comment: I added css to the jsfiddle and it still appears to work.  mb something else in your code is causing it?

Comment: My bad, I must have copied something wrong, it works perfectly now, thanks you are a rock star!

Comment: One other issue, the delete with with JS confirmation no longer works properly, it doesn't show the confirmation dialog box, if you have any thoughts, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the example with some untested code.  I'm not exactly sure how your data-method works.  But i think you can get the idea.  Basically just check for those data elements and do some things based on what you find.

Comment: Thanks again, the confirmation box works but it didn't send the right action, I'll fiddle with it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Bob, you might be running into stuff i also faced recently: Selected event fires on mouseup, i.e. before "li a" click handler. Should you want to handle anchor clicks first, you could either bind to mouseup for "li a", or, probably cleaner: Use "cancel" option on selectable, allowing selectable to disregard anchor clicks altogether. I've added a fiddle showing both options: http://jsfiddle.net/UUEwd/26/

Answer (score 0):

Well selectable can only select li's, and you only have one so it won't work the way you structured your HTML. If you put each element in it's own li, then you can individually select each one. I added CSS just so you can tell whats going on: http://jsfiddle.net/sEkPP/

Comment: You can select elements other than 'li' by using the filter option.

Comment: Actually a single element works as well, I can see it selected so that's not the issue, let me take a look at your CSS. I am going to update my example so it's more clear the level of selectable.

Comment: @Jason, I think what the OP wants is for the anchors to simply behave like anchors inside of the selectable li.

Comment: yes @fehays, that's exactly what I want. Yes, I have tried the filter option as well. I tried wrapping say the name, e.g, "John Doe" in a span and filter on span which works but anchors still don't act like anchors.